# Laravel Excel - Number value auto change

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-excel

So I have some data i saved it as Varchar on database, data ex:`3578012605010001` and when I export the data to excel, it'll change to `3,57801E+15`, then I tried to change it as Number, the result is `3578012605010000` i think it's works. But then i realize that it didn't, it change the last number from 1 to 0, that is not the exact data from the database. I wanted a result that export an exact data like `3578012605010001`.

Anw, this is my code to export from query to excel, im using Laravel Excel package.

```
class PengawasExport extends \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\StringValueBinder implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnFormatting
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        $dataTanggalMulai = Master::first();
        $dataTanggalSelesai = Master::first();

        $from = $dataTanggalMulai->periode_mulai;
        $to = $dataTanggalSelesai->periode_akhir;

        $pengawas = Penugasan::join('pengawas', 'penugasans.pengawas_id', 'pengawas.id')
        ->join('ujians', 'penugasans.ujian_id', 'ujians.id')
        ->groupBy('pengawas.nama', 'pengawas.nik', 'pengawas.pns', 'pengawas.bank', 'pengawas.norek')
        ->whereBetween('ujians.tanggal', [$from, $to])
        ->selectRaw('pengawas.nama, pengawas.nik, pengawas.pns, pengawas.bank, pengawas.norek, count(*) as total')
        ->get();

        return $pengawas;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Nama',
            'NIP/NPI/NIK',
            'Status Kepegawaian',
            'Nama Bank',
            'Nomor Rekening',
            'Total Mengawas'
        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'A' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER,
            'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'D' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'E' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER
        ];
    }
}
```

And here are my example datasets that i want to export

[image]

Comment: format your number as text instead (`NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT` instead of `NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER`)

Comment: @ChinhNguyen it'll return this value `3,57801E+15`

Comment: @Decrager just make the cell larger, the value of a cell and what you are seeing in the excel interface can be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this add '0' for specific columns you need to display the full number

```
public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            // F is the column
            'F' => '0'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: This still change the value `3578012605010001` to `3578012605010000`

Comment: I have another solution for you just need to change in config file excel.php change this line  'default' => Maatwebsite\Excel\DefaultValueBinder::class, to   'default' =>PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\StringValueBinder::class,

Comment: That works very well, thank youu

Comment: or you can use '#0' instead of 0 to prevent shortening and keeping the leading zero from a number (i.e. phone number column)